# Replicating color box in VScode when writing CSS

Tags: reactjs, design-patterns, colors, components, uicolor

I'm currently working on a project that basically shows a map. The map, image below, has different color gradients and I'd like to replicate the effect of vscode when you set color in css and it shows a little box that displays the color. I'd display that color and write a comment beside it.(I.E green = Great economy, light green = medium economy, and very light green = poor economy).

I'd really like to replicate the color display you see in vscode when you set color properties in css like this:
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open up settings in vs code (on a Mac, press command+comma)

Search for `Color Decorators` and check the box

[image]

More on vs code settings https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings

Answer (score 0):

I think you are asking about setting custom properties/variables in your CSS?

```
    :root {
      --some-yellow-you-name-here: #ffff00;
    }
```

```
    .you-class-name {
      background-color: var(--some-yellow-you-name-here);
    }
```